# How to get 2 touches on the same rectangle

Tags: java, android, graphics, andengine, touch-event

So i want to get two touches from one rectangle. So what i am doing is this

```
    Rectangle reset = new Rectangle(120, 40, 300, 100, act.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {


            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };
```

So this allows me to touch it. Dont worry i have registered all handlers and all that stuff. The thing i want to do is to touch one area and then touch another area and then draw a rectangle between the two touches. I am not quite sure how to capture the 2 separate touches. if any help is given i will be very thankful .

Comment: Save the first touch in a global variable. When a second touch is received, check if the touch variable is null. If not, draw the rectangle and clear the saved touch.

Comment: The problem is that i want it to be simultaneous

Comment: So you want multitouch?

Comment: No i want it like this. A person has 2 fingers on the screen and based on the x,y values i can draw a square between theme and then when they let go i will create a physics body and the cube will fall. But the problem i am having is that i cannot get 2 independent sets of values from each touch. Another thing i want to mention is that the person while their fingers are down can move it around until they lets go . then the cube will fall to the ground. if you can help in any way it would be much appriciated . thx

Comment: Sounds like you DO want multitouch.

Comment: I have already enabled it. I am not sure How to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
    float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                      // start X,Y
                }
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()) {
                      //what to do on move
                }
        if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                      // end X,Y
        }
    return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,              pTouchAreaLocalY);

}
```

maybe this is, what you search?